# How to prevent click action on children element?

Tags: jquery

I got a radio in div. Got function that changes the radio state when div is clicked. The problem is that when i click radio itself, action is being called twice (native radio click and div click), so it does not change it state. How do I prevent it? Tried `stopPropagation()`, `preventDefault()`, `return false`, but nothing.

```
$('div').click(function(e){
    var elem = $('input[type=radio]',this);
    if(elem.prop( "checked" )){
        elem.prop('checked', false);
    }else{
        elem.prop('checked', true);
    }

    if(e.target != this){  
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;    
    }
});
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/fH6nE/1/)

** I've edited a question to more adequate case, sorry for everyone, but those answers are not what I need **

Comment: _“I got a checkbox in div. Got function that changes the checkbox state when div is clicked.”_ – that’s what the `label` element is for; so use _sensible_ HTML instead of implementing already given functionality with JavaScript.

Comment: It's simplified case. If I could use label, I would use it!

Comment: I say you most likely could, unless you _prove_ otherwise by providing more info.

Comment: Please read edit. I need to unselect radio box. And the element that checks input may be much more complicated than some div! If I say label won't fit, it won't why to argue???

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to check whether the target is a INPUT element(since there is only a checkbox in the div if the target is a INPUT element then it is the checkbox), if so don't do anything.

```
$('div').click(function (e) {
    if (e.target.tagName == 'INPUT') {
        return;
    }
    var elem = $('input[type=checkbox]', this);
    if (elem.prop("checked")) {
        elem.prop('checked', false);
    } else {
        elem.prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9fuuq/)

Comment: Ok but when it will be radio that I would like to be uncheckable, it won't work. So, yes it is a solution, but not global.

Answer (score 0):

Try using, event.stopImmediatePropagation(). This stops the other events happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [e.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) for your `input`:

```
$('div').click(function(e){
    var elem = $('input[type=checkbox]',this);
    if(elem.prop( "checked" )){
        elem.prop('checked', false);
    }else{
        elem.prop('checked', true);
    }
});

$('input').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AqLpf/1/)**

---

EDIT: Hope this is your requirement:

```
$('div').click(function (e) {
    var elem = $('input[type=radio]', this);
    if (elem.prop("checked")) {
        elem.prop('checked', false);
    } else {
        elem.prop('checked', true);
    }
});

var radioStatus = false;
$.each($('input[type=radio]'), function () {
    // Set initial state of radio
    this.radioStatus = $(this).attr("checked") || false;
    $(this).data("status", this.radioStatus);
    // Set mouse-over event callback
    $(this).mouseover(function () {
        this.radioStatus = $(this).attr("checked") || false;
        $(this).data("status", this.radioStatus);
    });
    // Set on-click event callback
    $(this).click(function () {
        this.radioStatus = !$(this).data("status")
        $(this).attr("checked", this.radioStatus);
        $(this).data("status", this.radioStatus);
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fH6nE/5/)**

Comment: wow... a bit long solution... so there is no way to simply abort default behaviour?